# Mapping columns in oracle-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table:

```
column 1           column 2           column 3
2                  two                3
5                  five               8
3                  three              10
8                  eight              11
12                 one                15
```

I want to create a new column `column 4`like below:

```
 column 1           column 2           column 3       column 4
2                  two                3               three
5                  five               8               eight
3                  three              10              
8                  eight              11
12                 one                15
```

I want to map `column 3` and `column 1` and if there's a match `column 4` takes values of `column 2`.

Example: Value `3` in `column 3` is present in `column 1`, so `column 4` will take corresponding `column 3` value `three`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tt.column2 as column4
from table1 t left join
     table1 tt
     on t.column3 = tt.column1;
```

EDIT:

If you want to set the value, you can use `update`:

```
update table1 t
    set column4 = (select tt.column2 from table1 tt where t.column3 = tt.column1)
    where exists (select 1 from table1 tt where t.column3 = tt.column1);
```

However, this seems silly.  You can easily get the value in the table using an explicit `join` or hiding the logic in a view.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, I just have one table ```Table1```, and want to create(or add) a new column ```column 4``` to the same table

Comment: Pls let me know if I can modify above to one table alone @Gordon Linoff, Thanks !!

Comment: @omdurg . . . I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying you want to *modify* the table?  That seems a bit silly when you can just query for the value.